# Php, invokeArgs: parameters changed, how to return them?

Tags: php, reflection, pass-by-reference, variadic-functions

First of all, I want to test a function:

```
private function testMe (array &$output)
{
    $output['a'] = 3; // $$$$ $output gets changes
}
```

I made a little method to make it public, and call:

```
public static function makePublicAndCall ($objectInstance, $methodname)
{
    $ref = new ReflectionMethod (get_class($objectInstance), $methodname);
    $ref->setAccessible(true);

    $params = array();
    for ($i = 2+1; $i <= func_num_args(); $i++)
    {
        $params[] = func_get_arg($i-1);
    }
    $result = $ref->invokeArgs ($objectInstance, $params);
    for ($i = 2+1; $i <= func_num_args(); $i++)
    {
        // write back $$$$ here I would need something like "func_get_arg($i-1)"
    }
    return $result;
}
```

so, using it:

```
$output = array();
::makePublicAndCall ($object, 'testMe', $output);
// $output OMG output remains the same! It must not be empty but [a] => 3
```

see the problem? This method has 2 obligatory parameters, and all others are optional (they go to the invoked method itself). But if those parameters are changed, cannot be carried back!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### For PHP 5.6 and above

PHP 5.6 introduced variadic arguments, which can also accept parameters by reference.

```
function makePublicAndCall ($objectInstance, $methodname, &...$args) { }
```

now just forward the `$args` array filled with arguments by ref to `$objectInstance->$methodname`

```
function makePublicAndCall ($objectInstance, $methodname, &...$args) {
    $ref = new ReflectionMethod (get_class($objectInstance), $methodname);
    $ref->setAccessible(true);
    return $ref->invokeArgs($objectInstance, $args);
}

makePublicAndCall($object, 'testMe', $output);
```

### For PHP 5.4 and 5.5 versions

No, way, sorry.

### For PHP 5.3 and below

Call-time pass by reference still works with these archaic versions, so feel free to use it.

```
function makePublicAndCall ($objectInstance, $methodname) {
    $ref = new ReflectionMethod (get_class($objectInstance), $methodname);
    $ref->setAccessible(true);
    return $ref->invokeArgs ($objectInstance, $args);
}
@makePublicAndCall($object, 'testMe', &$output); // note the & here...
```

---

Also, you don't have to expect a reference in your `testMe` function, you get an array filled with references, that's enough; you don't need to get an array filled with references by ref to manipulate the references.

Comment: somehow the "For all PHP 5+ versions" version doesnt work... I have to stuck with Php 5.3

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, regardless of versions:

```
public static function makePublicAndCall ($objectInstance, $methodname, array &$params = array())
{
    $ref = new ReflectionMethod (get_class($objectInstance), $methodname);
    $ref->setAccessible(true);

    return $ref->invokeArgs ($objectInstance, array(&$params));
}
```

calling:

```
::makePublicAndCall ($object, 'testMe', $output);
```

EDIT: another solution regardless of version, but I bet you will throw your hat to the floor:

```
public static function makeStaticMethodPublicAndCall ($className, $method, &$params1 = null, &$params2 = null, &$params3 = null, &$params4 = null)
{
    $className = new ReflectionClass($className);
    $method = $className->getMethod($method);
    $method->setAccessible(true);
    return $method->invokeArgs (null, array(&$params1, &$params2, &$params3, &$params4));
}

    .
    .
    .

::makeStaticMethodPublicAndCall ('MyClass', 'myMethod', $param1, $param2);
```

Comment: That wasn't exactly what you asked. That's passing an array by ref, not variadic arguments...

Comment: yeah youre right. First it did solved my problems, but I realized its not good enough